# Printing one extra empty line at the beginning of output in C

Tags: c, printing, line, printf, output

Why is this printing one empty line at the beginning of the output? \n is only after %s... Help please, I'm so frustrated.

```
if(argc > 1){

    while(r!=NULL){

        r = fgets(str, MAXL, stdin);

        if(r==NULL){
            return 0;
        }

        if (*argv[1] == 'i'){
            char *invP = inv(r);
            printf("%s\n", invP);
            free(invP);
        }
```

inv() is:

```
char* inv(char* C){
int length = 0;

int i;
for(i = 0; C[i]!='\0'; i++){
    length++;
}

char *inverted;
inverted = malloc(length+1);
inverted[length] = '\0';
char* invP = inverted;

int j = 0;
for(i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    inverted[j] = C[i];
    j++;
}
return invP;
}
```

It doesn't have any print on it, dunno why is this happening.

Comment: You're going to need to show us more information. What does your `inv` function do, for example?

Comment: by the way: doesn't `free(invP);` create the problem?

Comment: @IlyaBoltnev No, because `inv` creates a new block of memory with `malloc` for its return value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `fgets`, your `r` string has a newline at the end. So, when you invert it (by calling `inv`), the string ends up with the newline at the beginning. Then, when you print it, you see the newline first.

```
r -> "hello\n"
invP = "\nolleh"
```

If you want to remove the newline, you can use something like

```
char *pos;
if ((pos=strchr(r, '\n')) != NULL)
    *pos = '\0';
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693826/57318))

Comment: Xymostech You're ABSOLUTELY right! I can't use strlib in this project, so I fixed it in my inv() method by switching 
     for(i = 0; C[i]!='\0'; i++){
for 
 for(i = 0; C[i]!='\n'; i++){

Thank you very much I was going crazy!!